# How to change object child members in a set

Tags: c++, class, object, set

I am using a set to hold objects. I want to make changes to the first object in the set. This is what I tried:

```
set<myClass>::iterator i = classlist.begin();
i->value = 0;
```

This is the error I get:

```
error: read-only variable is not assignable
```

How did the variable become read-only? How can it be changed?

Comment: Please tell us what `classlist` is.

Comment: classlist is a set that contains myClass objects.

Comment: err, sorry, what is `myClass`?  More specifically, how does it define operator< ?

Comment: I overload the < operator for set outside of myClass so that myClass can be added to the set.

Answer (score 1):

The things in a set are effectively read-only - you cannot change the value of a member of a set in situ. All you can do is remove it, and add a new member with the required new value. This restriction is necessary because of the binary tree implementation of std::set.

Comment: Are there any other containers similar to a set that are not read-only?

Comment: Yes, similarly you can't change the keys of a map.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to modify the element in `set`, the element has to be
once erased from the `set` and re-inserted in that `set`.
For example:

```
set<myClass>::iterator i = classlist.begin();
myClass c = *i;
c.value = 0;
classlist.erase( i );
classlist.insert( c );
```

If `operator<` for `myClass` doesn't refer the `value` member,
you can use `std::map` instead of `set`.
Assuming a new `myClass` which doesn't have `value` member,
and assuming that the type of `value` member is `T`,
then `std::map< newMyClass, T >` will meet the purpose.

Comment: You can't change the keys in a map.

Comment: @unapersson:
Thanks for the comment. However, I cannot see much relevance of the comment
to the answer, sorry.
The above answer doesn't state about the modification of the key in `map`.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles under VS2008:

```
#include <set>

struct myClass{
    int value;
    int comp;
};

bool operator<(const myClass& lhs,const myClass& rhs){
    return lhs.comp<rhs.comp;
}

int main(){

    std::set<myClass> classlist;
    myClass c;
    classlist.insert(c);

    std::set<myClass>::iterator i=classlist.begin();
    i->value=0;

    return 0;
}
```

But this only works by coincidence.  `operator<` compares the `comp` members and we change the `value` member.

Comment: This does **not** compile under GCC.

Answer (score 0):

in Visual Studio 2010 when Microsoft updated the STL, they made all iterators constant. So set::iterator and set::const_iterator are the same.

The reason is because in a set, the key is the data itself, and when you change your data, and thus the key, which is a no no.

The microsoft C++ team reported on this breaking change here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/25/stl-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-2010-beta-1.aspx

If you want to be modifying your data, and don't want to be removing and inserting, then use a map instead.