# a question in c++. just want a easy way to do this/

Tags: c++, class, stl

I have class

> class A { int x; int y}

and

```
set<A> myset;
```

how can I iterate this set? I want to touch x, y variable in the class.
Thank you

Comment: Did you intend `x` and `y` to be `private`? That is, are you asking how to access private members (*you can't*), or are you asking how to loop over the set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to touch x, y variable in the class.

In your class x and y are private. Members of classes are private by default. You can't just set x and y directly or else you'll get a compiler error. You need to provide a way to set x and y in the A's public interface, for example:

```
class A
{
int x; int y; // these are by default private
public:
   // set X
   void setX(int anX) {x = anX;}

   // set y
   void setY(int aY) {y = aY;}
};

// iterate over preexisting elements
set<A>::iterator iter;
for(iter = myset.begin(); iter != myset.end(); ++iter)
{
   iter->x = 5; // COMPILER ERROR, x is private
   iter->setX(5); //works, calls setter
   iter->setY(6); //works, calls setter

}
```

Another thing that prevents your set from working is the lack of an `operator <` for comparing to instances of A. `set` needs this to keep elements ordered and unique.

```
class A
{
   ...
   bool operator < (const A& other) const
   {
       // return true if this < other
       // up to you to define
   }
};
```

Comment: This works under VS2008 (Actually it doesn't, you still need an `operator<`), but under gcc (4.4.4) it doesn't.  I made the same mistake answering: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5876183/4834

Answer (score 2):

```
set<A>::iterator it;
for(it = myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); ++it)
{
    // your code
}
```

Alternatively you can use Boost::foreach:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(A& a, myset)
{
    // your code
}
```

EDIT: see comments :) all variables in A are declared as private, so there cannot be made any access. I guess there is no other way than to adjust the class and provide getters and setters or to make the member variables public.

Comment: oops, you are right. well then the class interface has to be changed I guess. your answer does it pretty nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

```
set<A>::iterator myIterator;
for(myIterator = mySet.begin();
    myIterator != mySet.end();
    myIterator++)
{
 // do something
}
```